what is "console.system()" in chrome dev version?
In the debugger console in Chrome Developer "Version 133.0.6847.2 (Official Build) dev (64-bit)", there is a "console.system(arg)" function which appears to be defined as:
{ pushToConsole(arg, "system") }
This function doesn't exist in standard Chrome "Version 131.0.6778.86 (Official Build) (64-bit)".
What does it do?

@MisterJojo:  https://docs.google.com/document/d/1gUSzgqC_IdsNhASO3UkGtwoWGHahwLBT4lMrYm_sbYY/edit?tab=t.0#heading=h.8p89ze8e15ml

There's no such thing in Chrome, so it must be something the site added.

@woxxom - good call!!  That's it.   Now I just have to try to remember where I was when I discovered that feature.
